# Mask expand, How do I create a unicorn horn style pattern?

Tags: masking, sculpt

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggOfOwRoYuM
in this video he makes a pattern but I still don't understand how to select the loop cut.....
and is there a way to rotate the mask?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the loop: In edit mode and edge select, hold Alt and select an edge, the whole loop will be selected.
To rip the loop, use the rip tool in edit mode (with the loop selected and the rip tool, drag from the circle and then right click so it snaps back to the original location).

Then go into sculpt mode and edit the mask.

- + to start masking
- /// to change falloff
- to increase count
- for gradient
- to add the current mask to the previous

Comment: ok, but how to cut the loop, to mask it start in the cut as shown in the video?

Comment: I updated the answer with more details.

Comment: thanks, he it makes a cut in the mesh! It's good, but sometimes there's a problem when it comes to inflating!